# Image converted to byte array and base64 not retaining height

Tags: c#, android

I've developed an Android app which captures a photo and sends it to web service, which is written in C#.

In the Android app I convert that image to byte Array and again convert it to base64 string and pass it to web service.

The problem is that image is uploading successfully but the size of that image is too small. E.g. when I open the photo the resolution is 1100x1200, but when it is uploaded on sever the dimension is 150x200.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

When I open photo on another device the size and resolution is also different.

Comment: post your code where you post the image to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code for image converting and sending to server.

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/MyImages/Image.jpg");

                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40 ,baos);
                byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

                try {
                    System.gc();
                    result = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
                    byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                    result = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.w("LOG", "Out of memory error");
                }

                Log.v("Image Conversion", result);
```